# Does the effect of a pulse gate using a custom gate reflect the effect of the pulse on the qubit?

Tags: qiskit

I'm calibrating a custom gate using Qiskit Pulse. The gate has no parameters. Does the result of the circuit accurately reflect the effect of the pulse of the qubit? That is, if I calibrate a custom gate with a Gaussian pulse (lets say amp=0.5 and sigma=16), is the output from the quantum computer/simulator purely the effect of the pulse? Or does the gate have some sort of warping effect?

Extra information: I need the statevector of the result of the pulse on a quantum circuit, so currently I'm using FakeArmonk from qiskit.test.mock and calling the get_statevector() function from the Job result.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by "the effect of the pulse" and whether you mean a real QC or a simulator. Do you mean that when you run a simulation using this, does it take into account the parameters of the gate? Or when you run it on a real quantum computer, are there additional pulse attributes involved in setting the operator that is actually applied?

Comment: @Lior "Do you mean that when you run a simulation using this, does it take into account the parameters of the gate?" I would like this question answered too actually, but originally I wanted to know whether the resultant state of the qubit after the custom gate is actually the state of the qubit after applying the microwave pulse with which the custom gate was calibrated, for both simulator and real QC)

Comment: I think what might help here is a bit of context. Are you asking a technical question about how qiskit works, or a general question about the effect of pulse distortions on the quantum gates that are applied to the qubits?

Comment: @Lior A techical question about Qiskit itself. Let's say that I know the exact Gaussian parameters for a Z gate. If I play a pulse with those parameters on a qubit via a pulse gate, will operate the same on the qubit like a Z gate would? (minus the noise)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pulse simulator in Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.PulseSimulator.html). When you submit a pulse schedule this will invoke the simulator under the Hamiltonian reported by the backend. Currently, the standard Aer simulator does not simulate pulse gates and you must instead simulate the underlying pulse schedule.